# How to convert formula to CNF?

Tags: formula, boolean-logic, conjunctive-normal-form

I know the 4 rules to convert the formulas to CNF, but I'm not quite sure how to apply them to this formula
((x v y) ^ ¬ z) ->w

Could someone give me a hand and a bit of an explanation? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the problem for you? Or where do you get stuck? Maybe this could help: *A -> B* is equivalent to  *not A and B*

Comment: Well if im not wrong the first step is to do
¬((X v Y) ^ ¬Z) v W 
(I THINK thats how it goes...but then I dont know if I'm supposed to move the not in one parenthesis or two, or if its two separate steps)

Comment: Can you describe your algorithm. You want a formula of minimal length? Or simply any CNF? We need more input to be able to help you.

Comment: This question does not appear to be related to programming. Perhaps it would be more appropriate on http://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Recipe for converting an expression into [CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form)**
One way to convert a formula to **[CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form)** is:

1. Write a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) (only the terms are relevant where the formula evaluates to false)
2. In every term of the [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) invert all literals
3. Take the resulting terms as [CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) clauses

**This recipe can be made plausible as follows:**
None of the clauses must be false, unless the overall expression is false. Therefore, every clause is representing a minterm of the inverted expression. To make sure that this term is false, none of the inverted literals can be true.

For n input variables, a truth table has 2^n terms. Therefore, this method is only practical for small expressions.

**To demonstrate the steps with your sample formula**

> ((x or y) and not z) implies w

Truth table (F = expression value):

```
wxyz|F
----+-
0000|1
1000|1
0100|0
1100|1
0010|0
1010|1
0110|0
1110|1
0001|1
1001|1
0101|1
1101|1
0011|1
1011|1
0111|1
1111|1
----+-
```

False terms (F = 0):

```
wxyz|F
----+-
0100|0
0010|0
0110|0
----+-
```

Literals inverted and output column omitted:

```
wxyz
----
1011
1101
1001
----
```

Resulting [CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) clauses:

> (w or !x or y or z) and (w or x or !y or z) and (w or !x or !y or z)

Resulting [CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) clauses minimized by merging clauses:

> (w or !x or z) and (w or !y or z)

If in doubt, you can ask [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28x%20or%20y%29%20and%20not%20z%29%20implies%20w).

From the [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map), it becomes clear how the three false terms can be merged into two clauses:

```
             wx
       00  01  11  10
      +---+---+---+---+
   00 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
      +---+---+---+---+
   01 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
yz    +---+---+---+---+
   11 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
      +---+---+---+---+
   10 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
      +---+---+---+---+
```